# Dot indicator for viewpager in Android similar like Instagram multi image posts

Tags: java, android, viewpagerindicator

Wanted to achieve dot indicator as attached image. I want if items are more than 
5 then small dot should appear and during sliding, it's resized. Check Instagram for live view(Look for any post which has uploaded more than 5 pictures)

I tried to play with the sizes of dots only and redraw them (by `invalidate()`) on every page change, however I couldn't achieve to maintain the dots in the middle. Playing with left and right dots wont make any big problem. but when the active dot is in the middle a scroll effect takes place. How can I achieve that?

I am holding a List of dots and play with the dots sizes and positions when page changes, than I invalidate and draw circles based on the dot properties in the list. However cannot find any idea on how to maintain middle dots so I can make that scrolling effect. Any other idea is appreciated

Dot indicator

[image]

Comment: i also want this feature on android.. right know.. only ios have it https://github.com/shima11/FlexiblePageControl..

Comment: here you go https://github.com/hrskrs/InstaDotView

Comment: Thanks ! It's exactly what i wanted.

Comment: This library https://github.com/shuhart/BubblePagerIndicator is more fancy than InstaDotView

Comment: you can checkout this post this just what you want: https://androidexample365.com/instagram-like-dot-indicator-standalone-view/

Answer (score 3):

you can checkout this library, 
https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator

Comment: Here dots are fixed to 5. I don't want to fix them. Kindly check once instagram example.

Comment: i think the indicators increase with the viewpager adapter's count()

Comment: My requirement is different, you can see 4th and 5th row in attached image. No matter how many items are there i need to show max 7 dots.

Comment: for that you need override `getCount()` in the `PagerAdapter`, the dots count will be depends on number you return in `getCount()`

Comment: I think you misunderstood requirement. I have to set max dot to 7 in case of more than 5 items. Then after sliding left and right dots should appear in less width and height.

Comment: updates for more  libs: https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/ScrollingPagerIndicator

Comment: https://github.com/shima11/FlexiblePageControl